# diacritics missing after importing CSV using BIML

Tags: csv, ssis, biml

I am importing CSV files using BIML. That works like a charm. However: there is one caveat.
In the imported data diacritics are replaced (eg: `Coupé` is imported as `Coup+®`)

Thse CSV seem to be standard CSV files. They are  stored on a Windows Share.
They are imported into a database with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.
The `dataflow` part of the BIML file looks like this:

```
                <Dataflow Name="Transport CSV_2_<#=imp_schema#>_<#=fileName#>">
                    <Transformations>
                        <FlatFileSource Name="SRC_FF-<#=fileName#> " ConnectionName="FF_CSV-<#=fileName#>"></FlatFileSource>
                            
                        <OleDbDestination ConnectionName="<#=application#>_<#=imp_schema#>" Name="OLE_DST-<#=fileName#>" >
                        <ExternalTableOutput Table="<#=imp_schema#>.<#=fileName#>"/>
                        </OleDbDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
```

What can I do to make sure diacritics are imported the same way they exist in the files?

Comment: Post the definition of your Flat File. My guess is you either need to specify unicode with a dt_wstr type or non-unicode but provide a different code page from 1252 to stay with dt_str

Comment: I will do. It looks like the issue is actually user/machine dependent. Will report back once I know more.

Comment: @billinkc You should get the credits for your answer!

Comment: Glad to hear it but go ahead and mark it solved - you need the points ;)

Comment: It is not so much the points, I really am grateful for your input. Maybe you will accept a heartfelt 'Thank you' for all your contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding CodePage = "65001"  to the definition of the flatfile